# Jquery enable/disable checkbox by name

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to disable checkboxes by name in the following table, but it is not working. Any suggestions, why?

```
<table border="1" class="myTable grid">
  <tr align="center">
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cb1;1" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb2;1" value="1" checked>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
</table>
<button id="button1" type="button"> DISABLE </button>
<button id="button2" type="button">ENABLE </button>
```

This is how I am disable/enable these checkboxes. I have tried .attr('disabled', 'disabled'); for disabling too.

```
$("#button1").click(function() { 
  var cbname = $j(this).attr("name");
  $("input[name='cbname']").prop("disabled", false);
});

$("#button2").click(function() { 
  var cbname = $j(this).attr("name");
  $("input[name='cbname']").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: `var cbname = $j(this).attr("name");`  .... but button has no name attr

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You have not assigned a `"name"` attribute to your buttons, so it is not finding the associated checkbox.
2. You are not escaping the `cbname` variable in your checkbox selector.

All together this should look like this:

**HTML:**

```
    <table border="1" class="myTable grid">
      <tr align="center">
        <td>A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="cb1;1" value="1">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="cb2;1" value="1" checked>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
    </table>
    <button id="disable" type="button" name="cb1;1"> DISABLE </button>
    <button id="enable" type="button" name="cb1;1">ENABLE </button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
   $("#disable").click(function() { 
      var cbname = $(this).attr("name");
      $('input[name="'+cbname+'"]').prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $("#enable").click(function() { 
      var cbname = $(this).attr("name");
      $('input[name="'+cbname+'"]').prop("disabled", false);
    });
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x324436z/

P.S.: I took the liberty of naming your enable and disable button ids appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Rour checkbox names are `cb1;1` and `cb2;1`, but you are trying to select `cbname`, try changing it to:

```
$("input[name='cb1;1']").prop("disabled", false);
```